# Как добавить к скрипту Lazyload?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Есть скрипт, проверка в котором должна выполнять после загрузки всех элементов на странице:

```
        if (height != 346) {
        $this.find('.price').css("top",(height+32)+"px");
    }
```

Как этого можно добиться с помощью Lazyload например?

Я понял в чем дело - в динамическом товаре цена формируется в атрибуте формы `data-product_variations`, а не в теге с классом `.price`. Вопрос как достать ценник остается открытым

```
<form class="variations_form cart" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" data-product_id="3348" data-product_variations="[{&quot;variation_id&quot;:3361,&quot;variation_is_visible&quot;:true,&quot;variation_is_active&quot;:true,&quot;is_purchasable&quot;:true,&quot;display_price&quot;:260000,&quot;display_regular_price&quot;:260000,&quot;attributes&quot;:{&quot;attribute_pa_size&quot;:&quot;medium&quot;},&quot;image_src&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;image_link&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;image_title&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;image_alt&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;price_html&quot;:&quot;<span class=\&quot;price\&quot;><span class=\&quot;amount\&quot;>260.000&nbsp;руб.<\/span><\/span>&quot;,&quot;availability_html&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;sku&quot;:&quot;PS104-1&quot;,&quot;weight&quot;:&quot; kg&quot;,&quot;dimensions&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;min_qty&quot;:1,&quot;max_qty&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;backorders_allowed&quot;:false,&quot;is_in_stock&quot;:true,&quot;is_downloadable&quot;:false,&quot;is_virtual&quot;:false,&quot;is_sold_individually&quot;:&quot;no&quot;},{&quot;variation_id&quot;:3362,&quot;variation_is_visible&quot;:true,&quot;variation_is_active&quot;:true,&quot;is_purchasable&quot;:true,&quot;display_price&quot;:130000,&quot;display_regular_price&quot;:130000,&quot;attributes&quot;:{&quot;attribute_pa_size&quot;:&quot;small&quot;},&quot;image_src&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;image_link&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;image_title&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;image_alt&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;price_html&quot;:&quot;<span class=\&quot;price\&quot;><span class=\&quot;amount\&quot;>130.000&nbsp;руб.<\/span><\/span>&quot;,&quot;availability_html&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;sku&quot;:&quot;PS104-2&quot;,&quot;weight&quot;:&quot; kg&quot;,&quot;dimensions&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;min_qty&quot;:1,&quot;max_qty&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;backorders_allowed&quot;:false,&quot;is_in_stock&quot;:true,&quot;is_downloadable&quot;:false,&quot;is_virtual&quot;:false,&quot;is_sold_individually&quot;:&quot;no&quot;}]">
```

Comment: К последнему Вашему комментарию под моим ответом - я подключил библиотеку jQuery и все одинаково работает в обоих случаях.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // когда HTML загружен и DOM готов
});


$(window).load(function() {
    // Полная загрузка страницы. со всеми изображениями, iframe и т.д.
});
```

Comment: к сожалению, 
`$(window).load(function() {
    // Полная загрузка страницы. со всеми изображениями, iframe и т.д.
});`
не спасает ситуацию.. мне подсказали, что можно попробовать через Lazyload, но я не знаю как..

Comment: под lazyload понимается очень многое. вот, например, для изображений - http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload какую задачу вы хотите решить то?

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // здесь код, который должен выполняться после полной загрузки страницы
});
```

Comment: нет, не то - у меня элементы формы загружаются самыми последними несмотря на условие, т.е. условие выполняется тогда, когда еще не все элементы загружены и соответственно не имеет на них влияния

Comment: поясните, как у Вас загружаются элементы формы? Через другой AJAX может быть?

Comment: если бы я понимал как- вопроса бы не возникло наверное. вполне возможно через другой ajax - как это можно понять?

Comment: понять можно, только глядя непосредственно на действующий код и на саму страницу. А из предоставленных Вами данных понять это также невозможно

Comment: а если допустить, что это 2ой ajax, то как действовать?

Comment: Простыми словами: когда выполняется AJAX (успешно) в функции "success" или "done" от jQuery запустить тот, код, который должен выполняться, когда все элементы формы загружены. А на пальцах-то не просто :(

Comment: `$(document).bind("ajaxComplete",function(){
  if (height != 346) {
        $this.find('.price').css("top",(height+32)+"px");
    }
});`
делаю вот так, но все равно не выходит...

Comment: Извините, но вряд ли смогу, и кто-либо, сможет подсказать в данной ситуации что делать, не имея полной картины перед глазами.

Comment: воспроизвел проблему здесь http://jsfiddle.net/ddupm8d8/2/
как видно из консоли: в первом случае (там где динамический товар и форма) скрипт не выполняется, а во втором срабатывает

Comment: что вам в этом примере в консоли то смотреть? http://jsfiddle.net/crybmxjt/ вот форк - два раза `269` - что не так? у вас в проекте случаем не нестандартные ли шрифты (те, которые вы подгружаете самостоятельно)?

Comment: @xaja шрифты roboto.

Comment: если убрать подключаемый шрифт - все ок работать будет?

Comment: @ вообщем, я понял, что цена формируется в атрибуте `data-product_variations`, а не блоке с классом `.price` - добавил в описание. осталось только ее оттуда как-то выцепить..